# Android keyEvent Escape never caught

Tags: android, keyevent

I got the following code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ESCAPE:
                this.buttonNegative.performClick();
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                this.buttonPositive.performClick();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
```

The event `KEYCODE_ESCAPE` is never caught. `KEYCODE_ENTER` works just fine and any other event is caught by my `default`. Why is this?